# Registration of mobile app URI name

Tags: android, ios, uri

This is a non-technical question.

Do we need to register or buy the URI name we use in our Android apps for deeplinks like website domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No,** the individual URI schemes are not registered universally, therefore, you don't have to register/buy them.

Comment: Thank you but then what if some other app is using the same URI. How will deeplinks work then?

Comment: @TapasMukherjee In my experience (on iOS, at least), the firstly installed app gets recognized.